# can we exclude/dont support specific device manufacture at manifest level.?

Tags: android, android-manifest, wear-os, samsung-galaxy, samsung-health

I am trying to develop a wearable application using Samsung Health SDK. Want to support only Samsung Devices(Watch, wear OS) only.

Can I add some specific code at the manifest level to exclude other manufacturers or include only specific manufacturer (in my case Samsung).
Please guide.